# Firefox hides empty table cells

Tags: html, firefox

I've written following HTML:

```
<table width="900px" style=" border-collapse:separate;">
        <tr>
        <td width="33%"  style=" empty-cells:show; background-image:url('box1.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; display:inline; margin-left:auto; position:static; margin-right:auto; height:300px; ">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td width="33%" style="empty-cells:show;background-image:url('box2.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; display:inline; margin-left:auto; position:static; margin-right:auto; height:300px; ">
        &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td width="33%" style="empty-cells:show;background-image:url('box3.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; display:inline; margin-left:auto; position:static; margin-right:auto; height:300px; ">
         &nbsp;
        </td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

IE9 and chrome show all the `<td>` s though they are empty. But Firefox does not. What has to be done to solve this problem?

Comment: Works fine for me in FF6 if I replace the background image with `background: red`. Are you sure that box2.png is being loaded properly?

Comment: Yes, works for me too - also note the cells aren't empty, they have `&nbsp;` in them.

Comment: @Marc B The problem was produced because of `display : inline` on Firefox 5. Images were anyway correctly loaded in IE and Chrome. I think they must have fixed this in FF6. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `empty-cells` CSS property should be on the `table`, not the `td` elements.  Also note, [support is buggy](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/empty-cells#compatibilitysection).

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `min-width` CSS property which FF supports.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a blank space in the cells with:

```
&nbsp
```

But most would say, not to use tables for page layout:
[Don't Use Tables for Layout](http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a table if you are in fact displaying tabular data, however.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: table-layout: fixed;

```
<table width="900px" style="table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: separate;">
```

Works in all browsers. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html